# How can I get the value of an input element inside a td for each row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I used this code to get to the **text** inside the first td element in each tr row:

```
 $('tr').each(function () {
        var tds = $(this).find('td'),
        text = tds.filter('[id^="refKey_"]').text(),
```

The HTML was:

```
<tr id="row_1">
  <td id="tempRowKey_1" >1.0.0</td>
```

However I have now changed my code and I have this HTML:

```
<tr id="row_1">
  <td id="tempRowKey_1" >
    <input type="text" size="10" value="1.0.0" class="updatable" id="TempRowKey_1">
  </td>
```

Can someone tell me how I can get the values such as "1.0.0" now that they are inside an **input**. Can I this time use the id of "TempRowKey_xxxx" ?

**Update:
I tried the following and also tried the answer given but neither work:**

```
    var tds = $(this).find('input'),
    text = tds.filter('[id^="TempRowKey_"]').val(),
```

can anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 7):

you should use `val()` for input elements, try this:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).find('input').val();
})
```

Comment: I tried this but I cannot get it to work. Can you fit this into using the filter and also getting the id. I have more than one input on each row.